# How to do 1's complement and add 1 in Android?

Tags: android, twos-complement

I am develop an application in `Android`. I receive the value from network and convert it by 1's complement.

---

For Example :

The value is `247`.

I convert the `247` to the binary: `1111 0111`

After the **1's complement** add 1 ,  the value is `0000 1001`.

Turn the the value `0000 1001` to the Decimal is `9`.

It mean the `-9` in my application , and that is the value what I want.

---

I try to use `Integer.toBinaryString` for convert the `247` to the `1111 0111`.
And use `for loop` to convert the `0 to 1` and `1 to 0`.
But it seems not a good method...

What should I do to implement the above example ?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by -1

2's complement already means ADD 1. If you just invert the number it is called 1's complement.

But the numbers are stored in binary already. If you get the number 247 it means you are treating it as UNSIGNED and you want to treat it as SIGNED. If it is 8 bits, treat it as a 'signed char'

Comment: Does there has any api to do 2's complement in Android ?

Comment: There's no api. internally negative number are always stored as 2's complement. You are probably storing what should be a signed byte in an int or unsigned byte.  Try just a cast:  (signed char)val;

Comment: or, if you really want to...  val=247;  val = ~val + 1;  (depending on language)

Comment: post some code if you need more help. I don't know your variable types.